# PVLIB TMY3 - able to work with 10minutes resolution?

Tags: pvlib

has anyone ever worked with TMY data with 10 minutes resolution? I tried to integrate it in my Code, but only get massive Errors after Errors...so I wondered if the TMYX function in PVLIb is at all able to work with anything else but hourly resolution.

Thank you very much!

Comment: TMY generally implies 1-hour data, so I wouldn't expect to find anything different. Where are you trying to get data from?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Adam Jensen pointed out earlier, TMY itself is a dataset with averaged 8760 hours of several years in hourly temporal resolution. Nevertheless, PVlib is actually able to work with any time resolution weather data specified in corresponding format. One can run [Model Chain](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.modelchain.ModelChain.run_model.html) function by feeding it with 10 minutes resolution dataset. The problem is to retrieve such data. However it is possible to use Solcast time series datasets for that purpose. You can check  [Solcast time series Data samples](https://solcast.com/historical-and-tmy/data-samples/). There are several time series climate data available (including solar radiation estimations) with global coverage. Data for one location is free